# My favorite paintings

Tags: wordplay, anagram

I only like one artist.  What are my three favorite paintings?

> Aerospace taper millionaires
>
> I remain separate solar police
>
> Oriole rat missile appearance
>
> American pirates aerosol pile
>
> No airier polecat armies lapse

Hint:

> The name 'Mona Lisa' can be found in the letters, but that's a red herring.  All five lines are the same letters, I was just having fun.  You only need one line.

Hint:

> Two of the paintings names contain a woman's first name.

Comment: the clues look like they might be anagrams.

Comment: @Jasen Rather likely, given the tagging ;-)

Comment: Is the name of the artist in the anagram?

Comment: @IAmInPLS No, the artist's name is not represented.

Comment: 5 lines that are all anagrams of each other. Not really even sure where to start with this one...

Comment: The second line seems to have an upper case i instead of a lower case L. Is this a clue?

Comment: @hexomino I don't think so, all the lines contains exactly three i, and all the lines begin by an upper case letter

Comment: This is very difficult. There are only 26 letters there and if they represent three distinct paintings that is an average of less than 9 letters each. Most works of art seem to have much longer names. Also, no H or D or U which seem to be very common letters in names of art.

Comment: @hexomino No, case is irrelevant.

Comment: @Vicky New hint to help address your concern.

Comment: I'm thinking so hard to Picasso but hey, his name must not be in the anagram :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I got it at last. The painter is, I believe :

> [John Singer Sargent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Singer_Sargent)

And the three paintings are :

1.

> [Elsie Palmer](http://www.wikiart.org/en/john-singer-sargent/miss-elsie-palmer-1890)
>  
>
>
>  [image]

2.

> [Rosina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosina_Ferrara), who was Sargent's muse.
>  
>
>
>  [image]

These two paintings are in accordance with the second hint : they both are named after a woman's name.

And finally the last painting :

3.

> [A Capriote](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:John_Singer_Sargent_-_A_Capriote_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg) (which also represents Rosina Ferrara).
>  
>
>
>  [image]

And now we can check the anagram :

> `Elsie palmer rosina a capriote` : `aaaaceeeeiiillmnoopprrrsst`
>  
>
>  `American pirates aerosol pile`  : `aaaaceeeeiiillmnoopprrrsst`

Comment: Nice!  I just don't know how to make a puzzle hard enough for you folks.